# Why do Windows file transfer speeds top out at around 1.5 gigabytes /second?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, file-transfer, ramdisk, m.2

I noticed that file transfers on the same machine between a fast nvme m.2 ssd (general read speed 3.2GB/s and writes 2.7 GB/s) and a ram disk top out at around 1.4-1.5 GB/s. Why is that the case? I run Windows 10 Pro Workstation as OS and turned off any firewalls, virus scanners or other overhead. The drives individually benchmark both above 2.5 GB/s for reads and writes. Why is a windows file transfer of a single large file capped at around 1.5 GB/s? I am purely assessing sequential read and write performance. Is there a cap in Windows 10 when it comes to file transfers?

Comment: Each buffer in the transfer has to be both read and written, so you should expect half the average read and write speeds at best.

Comment: Further limitations are : bus speed, driver speed, memory speed, CPU speed (interrupt commands are slow). All in all, it's very complicated to compute the real upper limit.

Comment: @AFH: The write is to memory, so in theory should be much faster.

Comment: Which file-system is used for source and target ? Using NTFS or FAT32 could be a major difference due to NTFS journalling. And which tool to do the copy with ? E.g. Windows own File Explorer is notoriously slow.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Try copying to `NUL:` from both the SSD and the RAM disc, and this will give you an idea of the system overhead.

Comment: @AFH, that cannot be the bottleneck. I actually have a raid 0 nvme config that has read speed of over 10 gigabytes per second and I can also equally fast write to ram disk. Still file transfers with windows file explorer top out at around 1.5GB/s.

Comment: @harrymc, I profiled all raw performances of ssd (actually raid 0 setup as mentioned above) and ram disk. Performance of read and writes are well above 8 gigabytes per second. There definitely is something else going on with windows 10 file explorer file transfer.

Comment: @Tonny, I formatted both with ntfs. But also tried fat32. Not much difference. OS yes windows 10 file explorer appears slow which prompted my question, my quest is to figure out why.

Comment: Are you copying a large file, or many small files? If the former, try `xcopy /J`; if the latter, the directory accesses will slow things down a lot. And I can't imagine what interfaces you are using for these performance figures (I assume you mean **Gb/s**): SATA is [limited to 6Gb/s](http://www.tested.com/tech/pcs/457172-why-storage-drive-speeds-dont-hit-their-theoretical-limits/).

Comment: Windows Explorer is known to be slow. Try using cmd with robocopy or TeraCopy.

Comment: @AFH, I meant gigabytes. I run a raid 0 of 4 Evo 970 each getting 4 pcie lanes. The disks are not sata, I thought that was apparent from the content in my question. Raw read performance with Intels's infamous benchmark tool puts numbers above 10 gigabytes per second and writes above 7 gigabytes per second. I do single file copy.

Comment: @harrymc, my entire question centers on why windows file explorer copy is slow. I will try a copy/xcopy as AFH suggested.

Comment: TeraCopy and Robocopy are faster. The fastest file copy program around is said to be the free [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/en/).

Comment: @harrymc,external transfer apps are not an option for me. I need to figure out why windows 10 file explorer copies are so incredibly slow. The same using of windows explorer file copy on windows server 2016 was not constrained. There is something else at play here and it seems so far nobody else knows why, either.

Comment: I have been avoiding for many years doing non-trivial copying with Windows Explorer. It's slow and has been slow since a decade at least. This is why I and others use third-party apps. Robocopy is at least is part of Windows, if it helps. FastCopy is the only one I know that claims doing parallel read&writes.

Comment: @harrymc, some findings: copy/xcopy is exactly as slow/fast as copying via Windows file explorer. TeraCopy and even FastCopy are 2.5x-3x slower. 3 files of 10GB each copied from nvme raid0 to ram disk on the same machine took 18 seconds to copy via copy/xcopy/windows-file-explorer. It took Teracopy and Fastcopy almost 60 seconds.

Comment: correction: FastCopy was actually faster and only took 8.5 seconds = 3.5GB/second. All other add-ons I tested were much slower than Windows file explorer. Unfortunately all those tests do not explain why single threaded file copy is so constrained. Most people might not complain about 1.5GB/second transfer speeds, but it is incredibly frustrating when you run a 100Gbit network and need data transfers from a nvme m.2 raid0 cluster with read speeds of over 10GB/second. I am almost tempted to pass through the ssd drivers to a VM under Linux.

Comment: So, multi-threaded copies push performance to about 5.8GB/second. That means all hardware components perform as expected. That leaves me at the moment to believe that the Windows Explorer data buffers and associated parameters are static and do not lend themselves to extremely fast hardware resources.

Comment: I summarized your results below. Feel free to edit my answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of the comments on the post and of the results of the tests conducted
by the poster :

- It has been found that all copy utilities
  functioned at about the same speed : Windows Explorer, copy, xcopy, robocopy,
  TeraCopy.
- The only utility which managed to reach the upper read speed of the disk was
  FastCopy.

The FastCopy utility distinguishes itself by doing reads and writes in parallel
and by not using the Windows cache for moving data.

The conclusion is therefore that the slowness experienced in copying files
when using the standard Windows mechanisms is due to :

- Lack of parallelism, so that reading is suspended while writing
- Inherent inefficiency in the cache mechanism of Windows.

The problem of slow file copy has been around Windows since a very long time
and since very early versions of Windows.
The above results might also explain why Linux is reportedly more
efficient on disk operations than Windows.

Comment: with all due respect but this is blatant plagiarism and on top of that entirely wrongly concluded. Robocopy can perform multi threaded copying. Also, your conclusions nowhere come even close to answering the question. "Windows slow file copies have been around for long time", so...., why bother? Is that your  honest conclusion? How did you earn 229k reps? Incredible.

Comment: Having read through your answer again, I decided to down-vote your answer. I generally do not down-vote any answers to questions I myself pose. But in this case...did you read through your answer again? Linux is more efficient because of above results? Would it not be better to only participate in questions that one can claim some expertise in? I am one of the top rated participants in the quant finance forum of StackExchange but would never dare to inject myself into topics I claim no knowledge of. I think you would do yourself a great service by deleting your answer here altogether...

Comment: I always try Windows Explorer in any new version of Windows, and they are always slow - personal experience does count for something. Linux is faster on file management - my personal experience again and that of many data-centers. Plagiarism of what ? I carefully didn't quote your results, just my suggestions. To remind you - your results *were* because of my suggestions, and thank you for having my convictions and experience verified here quantitatively. For multithreading in Robocopy - it still goes through the Windows cache, doesn't it, so evidently is still slowed down.

Comment: It happens frequently on this site that I explore an avenue with the poster and we arrive at an explanation or solution, together. Then normally the poster will ask me to summarize the results, which is what I did here. This is how I get much of my reputation. Evidently this is not your style, but please be more reasonable.

Comment: Note: If you would like to add your numerical results to my answer, please do so, or you may permit me to do that. If not, then no problem.

Comment: Your post does not answer the question posed. It only reiterates what I already stated. I asked why Windows explorer file transfers are slow. Staring that they have always been slow does not answer the question whatsoever. If you discussed potential bottlenecks in data flow between pcie devices and memory or bottlenecks when data are routed through the CPU or pointed to potential solutions such as smb direct/rmda then your answer would add value. As it stands it does not enlighten, clarify, offer solutions or offer other remedies. Enough said.

Comment: Edit: Meant SMB direct/RDMA

Comment: I understand this isn't your type of answer. You wanted a theoretical discourse and analysis, but unfortunately there isn't here any bottlenecks in pcie devices, memory or CPU, as such general constraints would have also applied to FastCopy. Some time ago I examined the source of FastCopy and found that there are no magic tricks, no direct access to hardware, only calls to standard Windows API. It really, truly, gets its speed by avoiding the cache and by issuing reads and writes in parallel, using lower-level Windows API. What is left to say about bad programming in Windows cache and drivers?